# Why is this recursive code so slow?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

This code for the first five iterations the speed is okay, but after that the speed is very slow, I cannot understand what is wrong with this? Would you please help me fix it?

```
Clear[A, r, x, s, e]
s := 0.3405
e := 1.6539*10^-21
u[0] := 0.
u[1] := 0.1

A[r_] := A[r] = 
  Piecewise[{{r - 2.5 s - 48*e *s^12*r^-13 + 24*e*s^6*r^-7, 
     r > 2.5 s}, {-48*e*s^12*r^-13 + 24*e*s^6*r^-7, 
     s <= r <= 2.5 s}, {r - s - 
      24*e*s^-1, r < s}}]
For[i = 2, i < 101, 
 i++, { u[i_] := 
   x /. FindRoot[
     u[i - 1] + 
       1/(i^2 (u[i - 1] - u[i - 2])^2) (u[i - 1] - u[i - 2]) - 
       0.9 A[x] == x , {x, 1.}]; Print[u[i]]}]
```

Comment: How slow? How many minutes/seconds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you learn the distinction between immediate (`=`) and delayed (`:=`) assignments. They make the difference between slow and fast code here. Start with [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) or [this book chapter](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html), then look at [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

```
s = 0.3405;
e = 1.6539*10^-21;
u[0] = 0.;
u[1] = 0.1;

A[r_] = Piecewise[{{r - 2.5 s - 48*e*s^12*r^-13 + 24*e*s^6*r^-7, r > 2.5 s},
                   {-48*e*s^12*r^-13 + 24*e*s^6*r^-7, s <= r <= 2.5 s},
                   {r - s - 24*e*s^-1, r < s}}];

u[i_] := u[i] = x /. FindRoot[
  u[i - 1] + 1/(i^2 (u[i - 1] - u[i - 2])^2) (u[i - 1] - u[i - 2]) - 0.9 A[x] == x, {x, 1.}]

Array[u, 100]
```

> {0.1, 1.77164, 1.37065, 1.04259, 0.887781, 0.708344, 0.59461, 
>   0.457228, 0.367364, 0.296071, 0.256104, 0.20463, 0.208487, 1.20917, 
>   1.04197, 0.939331, 0.879865, 0.827963, 0.774591, 0.72775, 0.67934, 
>   0.63666, 0.592369, 0.553172, 0.512352, 0.476112, 0.438261, 0.404563, 
>   0.369277, 0.339073, 0.321616, 0.301118, 0.296195, 0.224688, 0.273538, 
>   0.31357, 0.33593, 0.366902, 0.38813, 0.417572, 0.437777, 0.465834, 
>   0.48511, 0.511907, 0.530336, 0.55598, 0.573633, 0.598219, 0.615159, 
>   0.638772, 0.655054, 0.677768, 0.693441, 0.715321, 0.73043, 0.751535, 
>   0.766118, 0.786503, 0.800596, 0.820306, 0.833941, 0.852182, 0.85901, 
>   0.874152, 0.871531, 0.78396, 0.781416, 0.696402, 0.693931, 0.611329, 
>   0.608927, 0.528603, 0.526267, 0.448099, 0.445825, 0.369701, 0.367485, 
>   0.315658, 0.325798, 0.341207, 0.351098, 0.366134, 0.375788, 0.390468, 
>   0.399897, 0.414237, 0.42345, 0.437466, 0.446473, 0.46018, 0.46899, 
>   0.4824, 0.491022, 0.504149, 0.51259, 0.525444, 0.533712, 0.546306, 
>   0.554408, 0.56675}

(takes about 1.3 seconds)

Alternatively, use

```
Table[u[i], {i, 1, 100}]
```

(same result). Your combination of `For` and `Print` shows the results but doesn't let you keep using them for more calculations.

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `delayed` assignments definitely sound slower than `immediate`, even if I have never worked with Mathematica

Comment: @Roland it's not just that one is necessarily faster or slower than the other, it's more that they are completely different things with very different applications. For some reason this point is often overlooked by beginners in Mathematica.